# Jackson - Errors are being displayed in "Trace"\"Debug" log level

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

We are using a spring MVC project with jackson to marshal (json to pojo).

Problem is whenever we try to call a controller with an invalid object there is an error that is not presented in our default log level ("INFO"). is it possible to set jackson errors to a different log level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please try to add something like

```
log4j.logger.yourjacksonproviderpackagehere=INFO
```

to your log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

To change loglevel for jackson you could add

```
<category name="org.codehaus.jackson" additivity="true">
    <priority value="TRACE"/>
</category>
```

to your log4j.xml